# Can this kind of TDSE be solved by series?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, perturbation-theory

I have a particular kind of time dependent Schrodinger equation:

\begin{align}
i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Psi (t) &= \left(\hat{H_0}+ \frac{t}{\tau} \hat{H_1} \right)  \Psi (t) \\
\Psi (0) &= \Psi_0
\end{align}

$\tau$ is some suitable time scale. The initial state is normalized $\langle \Psi_0 | \Psi_0 \rangle=1$.
With appropriate coordinate transformation we can write $$\hat{H_1} =  i\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \, ,$$ So the full Hamiltonian appears to be Hermitian.

Let's assume the wavefunction can be expressed as Taylor series in time (I don't see why not).

$$\Psi(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n \left( \frac{t}{\tau} \right)^n \\ C_0 = \Psi_0$$

Then by direct substitution we obtain

$$i \frac{\hbar}{\tau} \sum_{n=0}^\infty C_{n+1} (n+1) \left( \frac{t}{\tau} \right)^n =\hat{H_0} \sum_{n=0}^\infty  C_n \left( \frac{t}{\tau} \right)^n + \hat{H_1} \sum_{n=1}^\infty  C_{n-1} \left( \frac{t}{\tau} \right)^n$$

Collecting the terms, we obtain the recurrence relation:

$$i \frac{\hbar}{\tau} (n+1) C_{n+1} =  \hat{H_0} C_n + \hat{H_1} C_{n-1}, \qquad n \geq 1 \\ i \frac{\hbar}{\tau} C_1=  \hat{H_0} C_0$$

This seems like a full solution, assuming we can apply the operators $\hat{H}_{0,1}$ as many times as we want.

> However, I have two questions:
>
> - Is there any problem with my derivation? In general $[\hat{H}_0, \hat{H}_1] \neq 0$, could this lead to any issues?
> - What about normalization? Would the series preserve the normalization of the initial state? If not, how do I fix that?

I know this is not the usual method for solving the TDSE, but I wanted to give it a try, since for my particular problem is seems the most suitable, as opposed, for example, to numerical scheme.

---

**Edit:**

About the explicit form of $\hat{H}_0$: I'm mostly interested in the case of exciton equation with confinement in one dimension, so it would look something like:

$$\hat{H}_0=- \frac{\partial^2}{\partial X^2}- \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}- \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \rho^2}- \frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial}{\partial \rho}+U(X,x)-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+\rho^2}}$$

Where I omitted all the coefficients for brevity. $X$ is the center of mass coordinate in one direction, $x$ is the distance between electron and hole in the same direction, $\rho$ is the distance in plane.

**Update 2:**

For what it's worth, I tried some numerical experiments in different representations, and it doesn't seem like this series converges at all. Maybe for some potentials it could be possible, but not for my case.

Comment: Expressing the solution as a series is only useful if you know 1) if the series actually converges at all and 2) what the radius of convergence of the series is.

Comment: @probably_someone, does it work if I'm pretty sure the series converges for any $t$? I'm fine with checking any particular cases numerically. I wanted to know if this solution is allowed at all (formally), provided the series converges

Comment: That depends on what "pretty sure" means. How did you come to this conclusion? And checking numerically is dangerous - how do you know that there isn't some really high-order term with a huge coefficient that makes your solution very inaccurate unless it's included?

Comment: @probably_someone, if you really want, I can add more details about what I'm doing, but let's just assume the series converges, I'm interested in whether or not I can *formally* solve the equation this way

Comment: Is $\hat{H}_{0}^{}\propto -\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right]_{}^{2}$? If so,it can be easily solved in Fourier domain.

Comment: @Sunyam, unfortunately no, it has potential terms and 3 dimensions (while H1 depends on a single variable only). I've tried Fourier transform, but the resulting integral equations were too complicated for me

Comment: Can you provide explicit form of $\hat{H}_{0}^{}$?

Comment: @Sunyam, up to unknown potential terms, because they could be anything, I would like a general method

Comment: @Sunyam, see the edit

Comment: Can gauge transformation of the sort $\Psi \to e_{}^{\kappa x t_{}^{\alpha}} \Psi$ help?

Comment: Your statements that $\hat H_1$ is real and that $\hat H_1 = A \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ are incompatible. The term "real" is generally a (discouraged) synonym of "self-adjoint"; is that what you meant by the term? In any case, why would you use the utterly misleading notation of giving the non-self-adjoint operator $A \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ the letter $H$? It should be exclusively reserved for self-adjoint operators, unless you're dead clear and explicit that it isn't, and handle it correctly.

Comment: As it stands, this question might be answerable, but the effort required to untangle the notational maze you've set up is rather beyond what you can or should ask of people here. Fix your notation to make it uniform and remove the misleading aspects, and *then* throw rep at it.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty, please assume I'm completely unfamiliar with the conventions you mention here. $A$ is a real number, that's what I meant, not that $H_1$ is a real operator. What other letter would you suggest I use for it? As it stands, I will simply remove all the coefficients to avoid confusion... As $i t/\tau H_1$ is simply a time-dependent part of my original hamiltonian, I used the same letter

Comment: I would **strongly** suggest that you incorporate the $i$ into the derivative, i.e. that you set $H_1 = iA\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, which is a self-adjoint (also called "real") operator, giving you the total hamiltonian $H_0 + \frac t\tau H_1$. Anything else is just causing confusion for no good reason. Similarly, if you're not prepared to explain in detail what you mean by a "real operator", don't use the term at all.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty, noted. I will change the notation as you suggest. I hope you understand that was an honest mistake, as my only knowledge of operators comes from introductory QM course and self-studies

Comment: The equation $\Psi(t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n (t/\tau)^n$ is confusing because it suggests that the wave function is a scalar at each point in time. Surely this is not correct.

Comment: It's also confusing that you'r using quote boxes to write parts of your post. Only use the `>` character on lines that are quotes taken from a book, article, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> Would the series preserve the normalization of the initial state?

Surely it won't. Your Hamiltonian isn't Hermitean.

> If not, how do I fix that?

Simply cancelling the "i" before $\hat H_1$. Why did you put it there?

Comment: The operator contains a first derivative only, so I'm pretty sure it's Hermitean because of $i$. That is, $$\hat{H_1} = A \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$$ where $A$ is a constant and $x$ one of the coordinates.

Comment: I remind you that $i\hat{H_1}$ looks like the $x$-component of a particle linear momentum $$p_{x}=\boldsymbol{-}i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$$ so it's hermitian. In other words  the hermitian conjugate of   $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ is $\boldsymbol{-}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$.

Comment: I have changed the notation due to the comments, so I hope this is less confusing now